# What is the effect of the energy stored in a capacitor on the current it supplies?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, capacitance

For say, what would be the difference between two capacitors with the same capacitance only one storing 0.5 joules and the other one 1 joule.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *performance*?

Comment: Per FakeMod you need to be specific as to what aspect of performance. Capacitors can serve many different functions.

Comment: They would have different voltages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the only difference between the two capacitors is the voltage across the plates, which accounts for the difference in stored energy based on the equation

$$E=\frac{CV^2}{2}$$

So the capacitor with more stored energy has a greater voltage. So, what does that mean in terms of performance? It depends on what aspect of performance can be adversely affected by either excessive or insufficient voltage.

One possibility concerns the fact that capacitors normally have some kind of maximum voltage rating. So if the higher stored energy is associated with a voltage that exceeds the maximum rating, damage to the capacitor may occur.

Beyond that, you would have to be more specific.

> Yes, I understand that the voltage supplied into the capacitor would
> have to be higher; however, I was more interested what would be the
> effect on resulting current, I am sorry for wording the question
> incorrectly

Well, if both capacitors were in the process of getting charged by say athe same battery in series with the same value resistor, the capacitor with the greater stored energy would be charging at a slower rate (lower current). On the other hand, if both capacitors were say discharging through the same value resistor, the capacitor with the greater stored energy would be discharging at a faster rate (greater current).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the voltage supplied into the capacitor would have to be higher; however, I was more interested what would be the effect on resulting current, I am sorry for wording the question incorrectly.

Comment: @Richard_Storm See my update

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed to know, thank you so much!

Comment: So is my answer acceptable?

Comment: It definitely is, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Richard_Storm I only asked because you didn't click the "accept" button at the end of my answer. Many new contributors are unaware of this option.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I was indeed not aware of this option.